# Progress meter on large uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added a progress "Donut" for my upload system. its similar to a horizontal progress bar, but circular.
It works great, but when i upload huge files like 200GB, my percentage makes the progress all jittery.

2 chunks would have these percentages:

68.0971237485292

68.12260919903389

on each chunk i update my progress. But since i have 3-8 chunks measuring 68%, it makes my progress glitchy.

This is what i do:

```
var total = fileSizeInBytes;
var current = details.receivedSize;
var Percentage = (current * 100)/total;
var donut = $('#donut_val').data('donut');
donut.val(Percentage);
```

How can i do this so that i ensure that before i set a new val for my progress, it has to be 1 number higher than the previous one?

Comment: My first thought is that you'll need greater granularity on your progress bar. Depending on the component you are using, it may be possible to increase that granularity. So for example, if your progress bar is 500 pixels wide, 1% would be 5 pixels wide, and .2% would equal 1 pixel. 

Without knowing what your `donut` is, it's hard to provide more specifics.

Comment: edited to explain the donut a bit better. its just like a progress bar, just circular with the percentage number in the middle. however, setting value is just the same as any other progress bars. set a value, and it shows it with colors.

Comment: You need to sum up all the chunks `receivedSize` and divide it by all chunks' `fileSizeInBytes` and use that for your progress donut.

Answer (score 0):

well, i solved it and wanna share my answer if anyone faces the same issue.
First off i rounded the percentage and did a check on previous percentage vs new percentage.

```
Percentage = Math.round(Percentage);
var donut = $('#donut_val').data('donut');
var curPercentage = donut.val();
if(Percentage > curPercentage){
    donut.val(Percentage);
}
```